# Inquiry Regarding Account Abstraction and Safe Gnosis Wallet Integration

Tags: safe-core, account-abstraction

I am currently exploring the concept of account abstraction and its integration with the Safe Gnosis wallet. My question pertains to the possibility of connecting an existing wallet, as well as various online accounts such as Gmail, Facebook, and Twitter, to a single Safe Wallet (that us implemented as a smart contract).

Is it feasible to consolidate these accounts within the Safe Gnosis wallet through account abstraction? I am interested in understanding the potential for seamless integration and the security measures in place for such a setup.

Thank you for your time and assistance. I look forward to gaining insights into this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`safeAuth`](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/guides/safe-auth) to link one (or multiple) accounts to a single Safe wallet, and use the [`salt`](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit/reference#deploysafe) parameter so that you can deploy the same safe for multiple accounts.

Hope it helps, Louis